# Can't create a Evernote Note with HTML content

Tags: php, evernote

I can't create formatted note in Evernote over the APIs. If I run the following PHP code I get an error:

```
$sandbox = true;
$key = "erersdfrtgsrttsdtgsr-3176";
$secret = "ejfiojsdfsdjfüjüsfjsdjfjsdfjüsefe";
$callback = "https://subdomain.saschak.ch/file.php";

$oauth_handler = new \Evernote\Auth\OauthHandler($sandbox);
$oauth_data  = $oauth_handler->authorize($key, $secret, $callback);
$token = $oauth_data["oauth_token"];
$client = new \Evernote\Client($token, $sandbox, null, null, FALSE);

$note = new \Evernote\Model\Note();
$note->title = htmlspecialchars($item["location_name"])." (".$item["image_likes"].")";
$note->content = new \Evernote\Model\PlainTextNoteContent("<a href=\"http://google.ch\">Test</a><br>Line two.");
$note->tagNames = array();
$notebook = null;
$client->uploadNote($note, $notebook);
```

After that I receive a PHP error.

If I change the string to the following or normal words then it works:
    $note->content = new \Evernote\Model\PlainTextNoteContent("http://google.ch\">Test");

I knows the ENML language but with this syntax in string I can't upload the note.

How can I upload formatted notes (HTML or ENML).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Evernote\Model\EnmlNoteContent` or `Evernote\Model\HtmlNoteContent`

Like:

```
$note->content = new \Evernote\Model\EnmlNoteContent(
    "<a href=\"http://google.ch\">Test</a><br>Line two."
);
```

`PlainTextNoteContent` is just what it says it is: plain text. It won't allow tags.

ENML notes do permit both `<a>` and `<br>` tags

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I saw but If I change the line as you said. I receve the following error:
Fatal error: Uncaught EDAM\Error\EDAMUserException in /my/root/path/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/NoteStore/NoteStore.php:13807 Stack trace: #0 /my/root/path/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/NoteStore/NoteStore.php(2393): EDAM\NoteStore\NoteStore_createNote_result->read(Object(Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol)) #1 /my/root/path/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/NoteStore/NoteStore.php(2353): EDAM\NoteStore\NoteStoreClient->recv_createNote() [...]

Comment: Just close the br tag : <br /> instead of <br>

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the <br/>!